# Mutex lock does not work as expected in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, mutex

I try to implement a Hospital Simulation Project with threads but the mutex lock does not work as expected registration size should not be lower than zero if registration size is equal to zero then threads must wait for increment but if I increment the number of patients (they are also threads) registration size can be lower than 0. Why is that happening?

```
int REGISTRATION_SIZE = 10;
pthread_cond_t condRegister;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
```

Patient:

```
struct Patient {
    struct Disease disease;
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int thread_num;
    int Hunger_Meter; // Initialized between 1 and 100 at creation.
    int Restroom_Meter; // Initialized between 1 and 100 at creation.
};
```

Thread function:

```
void *thread_func(void *p){
    struct Patient *patient = (struct Patient*)p;
    registration();
    return NULL;
}
```

Sleep method:

```
void sleepForMs(int ms){
    usleep( 1000 *  ms);
}
```

Thread Usage:

```
void registration(struct Patient *p){
    int rnd_wait_time;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&registration_mutex);
    while(REGISTRATION_SIZE == 0){
        rnd_wait_time = generate_rnd_numb(WAIT_TIME) + 1;
        //printf("Patient[%d] waiting for an availabe desk.\n",p->thread_num);
        sleepForMs(rnd_wait_time);
        increase_meters(p);
        checkForRestOrCafe(p);
        pthread_cond_wait(&register_cond,&registration_mutex);
    }
    REGISTRATION_SIZE--;
    printf(" Registration size: %d \n", REGISTRATION_SIZE);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&registration_mutex);

    int register_time = generate_rnd_numb(REGISTRATION_TIME) + 1;
    sleepForMs(register_time);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&registration_mutex);
    REGISTRATION_SIZE++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&registration_mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&register_cond);
}
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&condRegister, NULL);

    srand(time(NULL));
    int NUMB_OF_PATIENT = 3000;

    struct Disease *diseases = malloc(sizeof(struct Disease));
    diseases = create_diseases();
    
    struct Patient patient[NUMB_OF_PATIENT];

    create_patients(patient,NUMB_OF_PATIENT,diseases);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMB_OF_PATIENT; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&(patient[i].thread_id), NULL, thread_func, (void *)(patient + i));
    }

    //wait for all threads
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMB_OF_PATIENT; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(patient[i].thread_id, NULL); 
    }
    
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&condRegister);
    return (0);
}
```

Divide Registration into functions:

```
void wait_for_available_resource(struct Patient *p, pthread_mutex_t mutex, pthread_cond_t cond, int resource){
    int rnd_wait_time;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(resource == 0){
        rnd_wait_time = generate_rnd_numb(WAIT_TIME) + 1;
        sleepForMs(rnd_wait_time);
        increase_meters(p);
        checkForRestOrCafe(p);
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
    }
    resource--;
    printf(" Resource Number: %d \n", resource);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void spend_process_time(int needed_time){
    int elapsed_time = generate_rnd_numb(needed_time) + 1;
    sleepForMs(elapsed_time);
}

void release_resource(pthread_mutex_t mutex, int resource_number, pthread_cond_t cond){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf("-----------\n");
    printf("resource number:%d\n",resource_number);
    resource_number++;
    printf("resource number:%d\n",resource_number);
    HOSPITAL_WALLET += REGISTRATION_COST;
    printf("-----------\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
}

void registration(struct Patient *p){
    wait_for_available_resource(p,registration_mutex,register_cond,REGISTRATION_SIZE);
    spend_process_time(REGISTRATION_TIME);
    release_resource(registration_mutex,REGISTRATION_SIZE,register_cond);
    
}
```

Comment: 1. It doesn't make sense for every thread to call `pthread_mutex_init`. It should only be called once in the main thread. 2. `while(REGISTRATION_SIZE == 0)` is not protected inside a mutex lock so will result in a race condition.

Comment: When I protect while loop with mutex lock I can not get any output. How can I protect while loop?

Comment: Where is `REGISTRATION_SIZE` defined? It is _set_ later in `registration` but _that_ code will _never_ execute because the `while (REGISTRATION_SIZE == 0)` will loop infinitely because it is _never_ changed inside the loop. (i.e. _All_ threads will spin/block on their respective loops at that point). And, as kaylum suggested take the mutex init out of the function and do it _once_ (e.g. in `main`).

Comment: You can't just mutex lock the whole loop. That will cause a deadlock as you are finding out as nothing else will be able to change the counter. The standard way is to use [conditional variables](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait).

Comment: I got intuition through your comments I will try to understand deeply. Thanks.

Comment: You do not want to unlock and lock again after getting out of the loop. The loop with the condition wait is making sure a precondition is met before entering the body of the thread. If you unlock and lock, you open up the thread body to some other thread making the precondition false again. Hold the lock continuously while the precondition is right until the work is completed, then release the lock.

Comment: Did you mean that I should release the lock once after  REGISTRATION_SIZE++; ?

Comment: When I lock the whole work REGISTRATION_SIZE can not be lower than 10 because one thread can access the registration method. I want the registration method can be accessible by 10 threads in the same time.

Comment: Rethink your code as two separate operations that need to be thread safe. `register()` and `unregister()`.

Comment: The decrement happens during `register()`. The increment happens during `unregister()`. Between the two operations, there is a wait time.

Comment: I don't know why but when I divide it into functions it acts differently. I can not get expected results.

Comment: I guess I can't pass mutexes into functions correctly.

Comment: If you use `pthread_cond_signal` then the woken up thread is in charge of raising another signal if the condition is still true. So after decrement, if the value is positive, raise a signal for the next thread.

Comment: Alternatively, you can change your current code to use `pthread_cond_broadcast`. However, I think using `pthread_cond_signal` is a more efficient solution.